# Read every line from a website with Python

Tags: python, output

I'm looking to read every line off a webpage while there are lines. So far I have the code below. I cannot get it to assign temp the value of each line, which i'm looking to use regex to check to see if the line meets a specific format.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib2
import re

#imported urllib to collect the data. imported re for regular expressions to     test format.


#creating our output file
f=open("OUIoutput.txt", "w+")

#opening a file like object using urllib
webpage= urllib2.urlopen("https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=manuf")


#string used to store the output
str1=""

#string used to store current line
temp=""



#while loop to read in the data for every line.INCORRECT FOR LOOP BASIC PLACEHOLDER IN THE CODE
for i in (60,500):
    temp=webpage.readline(i)
    if re.search("\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", temp):
      str1+=temp

f.write(str1)
```

Comment: What are you getting? Exception? Unwanted output?

Comment: @SpiderMan No output... but most importantly for now I need to figure out how to read every line while there is a line in the file

Comment: In the file? HTML file?

Comment: do u wanna parse the webpage ? since reading every line cud mean u would get the page src code too ...

Comment: @SpiderMan Oh I have output! I simply changed to `i in RANGE(60,500)` which is good, but now I just need to figure out how to loop without numbers, just until there are no more lines.

Comment: @ArchitGarg I want to read every line on that webpage (i'm checking to see if each line follows the format, and if it does then I am going to output it). So instead of me saying for i in a range I just want it to go to the end of the file if that makes sense

Comment: Use _for line in webpage.readlines(): print line_

Comment: @SpiderMan my hero!! You're the best!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answering as per your comment:**

You don't need to use range for this. [readlines](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)() function is what you are looking.

```
for line in webpage.readlines():
    #do your work here
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single call to `re.findall`, taking advantage the MULTILINE flag:

```
import requests
import re

pattern = re.compile(ur'^.*\w\w:\w\w:\w\w.*$', re.M)
url = "https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=manuf"
webpage = requests.get(url)
print u'\n'.join(pattern.findall(webpage.text)).encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: And may be loop through them. +1 for the alternative answer